# Migrating ArcView GIS *.apr to ArcMap application of ArcGIS Desktop 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, arcview-3

I have a lot of arcview .apr file. I need to open & edit in ArcMap 9.3, but the original project file is saved in .apr. I tried to use "import from arcview project". The project file can be open finally, but some data source was broken. I cannot trace the original data file, as the layer name was assigned by anothers. How can I trace the data file and re-link it in Arcmap 9.3?

Comment: Since .apr files were clear text and layer properties will report the data source, I'm wondering why you didn't search for the source path in the .apr file.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in a comment by @Vince:

> Since .apr files were clear text and layer properties will report the
>   data source, [you could] search for the source path in the .apr file.